# Dlib for javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, dlib

I am fairly new to C++ and also Dlib. I need to work on a facial landmark detector for browser and was wondering if someone has tried compiling DLIB with e.g. ASM.js to work on a browser. I have not seen many DLib facial landmarking live demos on the web.

Is it a worthwhile idea to pursue? If yes, could someone direct me to any resources?

Comment: Are you trying to build a system that should work directly inside browser via JS or with some server-based backend? Or may be you want to build some kind of browser extension?

Comment: ASM.js looks a bit dead - might not be worth investing too much effort only to discover that there are some incomplete bits

Comment: I am trying to build a client side JS solution that could use Dlib. Similar to the clmtrackr.js or tracker.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also face same problem in one of the my project. But i successfully get face landmark details  from dlib with browser.

Actually i get image from user and send to server save it one specific folder. then trigger dlib `python` code through  `PHP` and get landmark point details as a `json` format. once we get a point details we can do anything with that.

idea is

input image file --> send to serve --> save to folder --> trigger dlib python script --> save point as a json file --> echo to success --> get json

through this way:

**STEP 1:**
first install Dlip on your server successfully(first tested your local server)  without any error. and check it its run without error.

**STEP 2:**
Then we want face landmark from dlip. dlip have a example script `face_landmark_detection.py`  we can use this.

my customized `face_landmark_detection.py` script this is save point details as a json file in specific path:

```
# python face_landmark_detection.py "predictor.dat" "folder/image.jpg" "folder/test.json" 

import dlib
import glob
import json
import os
from skimage import io
import sys



predictor_path = sys.argv[1]
#faces_folder_path = sys.argv[2]
image      = sys.argv[2]
json_path  = sys.argv[3]

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)






img = io.imread(image)
dets = detector(img, 1)
print(dets);
print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(dets)))
for k, d in enumerate(dets):

    print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(
          k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))

    # Get the landmarks/parts for the face in box d.
    shape = predictor(img, d)

    print("Part 0: {}, Part 1: {}, Part 3: {}  ...".format(shape.part(0),
          shape.part(1), shape.part(2), ))
    part1 = shape
    data = {}
    num = 0
    for n, p in enumerate(shape.parts()):
        n = format(n)
        p = format(p)
        p = p.split(",")
        x = p[0].split("(")
        x = x[1]
        y = p[1].split(" ")
        y = y[1].split(")")
        y = y[0]
        print(n, x, y)
        data[n] = {'x':x, 'y':y}
    out_file = open(json_path, "a")
    json.dump(data, out_file, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    json_data = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True);     
    print(json_data)
```

my server `php` script . this script get image from browser and save it in some folder and trigger my `face_landmark_detection.py` with predictor path ,image path, json path arguments.

`server.php` file like this

```
<?php

$target_dir = "/designing/face/uploads/";
$type = explode("/", $_FILES["file"]["type"]);
$type = $type[1];
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {

        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {

        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    unlink($target_file);
    $uploadOk = 1;
}
// Check file size
/* if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
  } */
// Allow certain file formats
if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "png") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "error";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        //chmod($target_file, 0777);
        //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

        if ($imageFileType == "png") {
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($target_file);
            $bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
            imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
            imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
            imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
            imagedestroy($image);
            $quality = 100; // 0 = worst / smaller file, 100 = better / bigger file 
            imagejpeg($bg, $target_file . ".jpg", $quality);
            imagedestroy($bg);
            unlink($target_file);
            $target_file = $target_file . ".jpg";
            //echo $target_file;
        }

        $json_file = fopen("/test/json/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "_json.txt", "w");
        if ($json_file) {
            $command = 'python /face/face_landmark_detection.py "/face/predictor.dat" "' . $target_file . '" "/test/json/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . '_json.txt"';
            $output = shell_exec($command);
            if ($output) {
                //unlink($target_file);
                echo "ok";
            }
        }




        //echo $command;
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

and my client (browser) side script like this

```
$('#file').change(function() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    img = $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0];
    file_name = img.name;
    console.log(file_name);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
        data_url = readerEvt.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(img);
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "server.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data === "ok") {
                getJson(data_url, file_name);
            } else {
                alert("something worng");
            }
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
var pts;

function getJson(data_url, file_name) {
    console.log(file_name);
    var json_name = {
        'name': file_name
    };
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: base_url + "get_json.php",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: json_name,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            pts = data;
            console.log(pts);
            // alert(data_url);
        }
    });
}
```

once everything run good we get a json file with points . We can play what we want on canvas with these point. first you have to understand the whole process.

I am directly pasting my demo code here. Look the code and change what you want (like path, parameters... ) then run.

I am successfully get point details with these way for My virtual face make over project. I cant give you a my project url for your demo because project currently under process.

Comment: Does your Dlib code need to load [shape model file](http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2) at everytime you call your `face_landmark_detection.py` program.

Comment: So if there come ten request to your server then does [shape model file](http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2) is loaded in each program instance seperately. Does this not increase memory consumption on your server.

Comment: defiantly that's make memory issues.. currently our project is under process.. so not too much issues now. but we have to think about it for The future process.. do you have any idea for this..?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of Python. But as in C++ file can be stored in static buffer and can be shared between many objects. You can do similar in Python, If it is possible.

Comment: @AkshayHazari ... yes its possible on web cam via python ...many open source library available on web.... i personally tried     [face-recognition](http://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)..its work awesome

Comment: @sharma sk . I meant facial landmarks using javascript in your browser, the way clmtracker https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr works. Just that inspite of using dlib its not that good.